# Android. Изменяемая константа элемента в файле

Tags: java, android

**Имеется вот такой код:**

```
                                       ...

                public static final String APP_STORAGE = "AppStorageFile";                    
                public static final String Name_1 = "TextName7";
                private SharedPreferences SFE;

                @Override
                    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                    {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        SFE = getSharedPreferences(APP_STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                       ...

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SFE.edit();
                        editor.putString(Name_1, "Привет мир"));
                        editor.apply();

                        i = 1;

                        String Name_number = "Name_" + String.valueOf(i);
                        Log.d("TAG_LOG", Name_number);
                        if (SFE.contains(Name_number))
                        {
                            Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Зашло");
                        } else{
                            Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Не зашло");
                        }
                    }
```

> В итоге, в логах пишется:
>       `Name_1`
>       `Не зашло`

Как правильно написать, чтобы мне выдавало в логах `Зашло` и при этом иметь возможность изменять значение в скобках.

> Для каждого `Name_i`, где *i=1,2...100* имеется один и тот же код. И чтобы
>   его не расписывать 100 раз, я как раз и решил использовать 
>   `String Name_number = "Name_" + String.valueOf(i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо путать имя переменной с её значением. В качестве ключа используется значение, то есть строка, которую Вы присваиваете переменной(`"TextName7"`) - именно она и записывается в `SharedPreferences`.
То что Вы хотите должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
    public static final String KEY_PREFIX = "Name_";
```

---

```
       i = 1;
       String nameNumber = KEY_PREFIX + i;
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SFE.edit();
       editor.putString(nameNumber, "Привет мир"));
       editor.apply();
       Log.d("TAG_LOG", nameNumber);
       if (SFE.contains(nameNumber)) {
            Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Зашло");
       } else {
            Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Не зашло");
       }
```

Comment: Всё равно `Не зашло` :(

Comment: @Михаил, значит Вы всё равно что-то делаете не так - код рабочий 100%. Ключевой момент этого вопроса  - значение ключа должно быть одинаковым в `put` и `contains`.

Comment: Ваш, код правильный. Оказалось, что сохранять в `Name_ 1` и сохранять в `Name_ + i` , где `i=1` - не одно и тоже. Выражаю вам  огромную благодарность.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь сложить строку с числом без явного приведения к строке. Попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
            public static final String Name_1 = "TextName7";
            private SharedPreferences SFE;

            @Override
                protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                                   ...

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SFE.edit();
                    editor.putString(Name_1, "Привет мир"));
                    editor.apply();

                    String Name_number = "Name_" + "1";
                    if (SFE.contains(Name_number))
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Зашло")
                    } else{
                        Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Не зашло")
                    }
                }
```

Здесь в строке

```
   String Name_number = "Name_" + "1";
```

Происходит сложение строк и получается корректная строка для сравнения

Comment: Не, тоже `Не зашло`. :(

Answer (score 0):

Вы проверяете существует ли у вас в настройках поле Name1. И правильно он вам выводит "не зашло", потому что у вас такого поля нет. Вы создаете поле, название которого определяете через переменную Name1, значение которой - TextName7. Сделайте проверку

```
if (SFE.contains(TextName7))
```

и у вас выведет "Зашло"

Comment: Если я напишу `if (SFE.contains(Name_1))`, то всё работает. Но дело в том, что мне как раз и нужно иметь возможность изменять значение в скобках, т.е. использовать `Name_2`,`Name_3` и т.д.

Comment: Для каждого `Name_i`, где i=1,2...100 имеется один и тот же код. И чтобы его не расписывать 100 раз, я как раз и решил использовать `String Name_number = "Name_" + String.valueOf(i);`

Comment: возможно, лучше будет использовать массив или List для таких целей